# using the gen function in gaussian

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian

I'm trying to optimize a structure that contains Pd atom with the gen function on gaussian16

```
    %chk=pd3cgen.chk
    # opt freq b3lyp/gen pseudo=read scrf=(solvent=ch2cl2,read,pcm)

        Zmatrix coordinates
               .....

pd 0
 LANL2DZ
 ****
 S 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 O 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 Br 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 C 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 H 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 N 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 Cl 0
 6-31G(d)
 ****
 blank space
  radii=uaks
```

I have done before the calculation with only lanl2dz alone it worked perfectly but when I used a mixing basis set(this case) I got this error message:

```
Maximum number of bonds 12 exceeded for atom  13.
 Error termination via Lnk1e
```

Comment: You may be able to avoid this error by manually entering the connectivity with `geom=connectivity`.

Comment: @Tyberius it still displays the same problem

Comment: This message surely does not have anything to do with a basis set and most certainly points to some issue with Z-matrix. Try to replace Z-matrix with plain xyz coordinates to check if that's the case.

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is that you need to specify both pseudo-potential and basis set for Pd, please see the example in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that for atoms with pseudo-potential you need to define both localized and pseudo-potential parts. Here's example for your input:

```
END-OF-GEOM-BLOCK

H C N O S Cl Br 0
6-31G(d)
****
Pd 0
LANL2DZ
****

Pd 0
LANL2DZ

radii=uaks
```

Comment: thank you so much  that's what I actually did this morning and it worked but I still don't understand how it worked , is it because of the frozen core electrons?

Comment: exactly, and I'm not sure why is that an option since basis set and pseudo-potential are usually optimized together forming one "pseudopotential". Seems like it's some kind of legacy of quantum chemistry 30 years ago :-)

Comment: although, when using only lanl2dz without the gen keyword It seems like I got better results when compared to experimental + the computational cost is cheaper . is it ok to just keep a one basis?